# LiveData Observer does not update UI after data fetched from server in ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am trying to fetch data from the server using retrofit get request, in the ViewModel, I initiate the request, OnResponse method of the request shows the data successfully being retrieved from the server but the observer in the fragment doesn't get updated. I am sharing the code below.

**RETROFIT API CALL**

```
fun getGenres(application: Context,callback:(List<Genre>)->Unit){
        val baseURL = "https://listen-api.listennotes.com/"
        var genreList: MutableLiveData<List<Genre>> =MutableLiveData()
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
//      set your desired log level
        logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
//      add your other interceptors …
//      add logging as last interceptor
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging)

        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build()

        val api: ApiFunctions = retrofit.create(ApiFunctions::class.java)



        val call: Call<PodcastGetCategoryResponse> = api.getGenres()

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<PodcastGetCategoryResponse> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<PodcastGetCategoryResponse>, t: Throwable) {

                Toast.makeText(application, "failure" + t.stackTrace, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<PodcastGetCategoryResponse>,
                response: Response<PodcastGetCategoryResponse>
            ) {


                response.body().apply {
                    callback(this?.genres!!)                    }
                Toast.makeText(application, "success: ${response.body()?.genres?.size}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }

        })

        return genreList;
    }
```

This runs successfully and retrieves a list of Genres from the server.

**VIEWMODEL CLASS**

```
class CategoryViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
private val rootJob = SupervisorJob()

private val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = Dispatchers.Main + rootJob

 var listOfCategory: MutableLiveData<List<Genre>> = MutableLiveData()

init {
    getistOfCategory()
}

// this method is responsible for retrieving data from the result of the API call method using a coroutine.

 fun getistOfCategory() {
    CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch() {
        ApiFunctions.getGenres(getApplication<Application>(), { l -> listOfCategory.value = l } )
         listOfCategory.postValue(listOfCategory.value)
    }
  }
```

I assume that issue lies in this class but I can't figure it out.

**FRAGMENT Class **

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var viewModel: CategoryViewModel
private lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CategoryViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.getistOfCategory()

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    binding =DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    var myView: View = binding.root




    viewModel.listOfCategory.observe(this,
        Observer { list ->
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Data Changed" + list?.size,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        })

    return myView
}
```

What I want is that when new values are retrieved from the server it should be saved in LiveData in ViewModel class and the fragment should successfully observe them.

Comment: Try this

CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch() {
      listOfCategory.postValue(ApiFunctions.getGenres(getApplication<Application>()).value)
    }

Comment: try categoryList.value= the response

Comment: Thanks, @KishanMaurya, the observer started working but right now the observer observes the initial value of the list, the response from the server comes after few seconds. Shouldn't the observer detect new values and show a toast message?

Comment: Yes, In that case, you have to use awaitAndGet()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to your current implementation the value of `listOfCategory` keeps changing with each update. this means when your list is updated the observers are not being notified cause they're observing another LiveData object (which was assigned to your reference before the update occurred)
You need to make sure that you instantiate the liveData object only once and update its value whenever you get an update.

Your code should look something like this

```
fun getGenres(application: Context, callback:(List<Genre>)->Unit){
...
     response.body().apply {
            callback(this?.genres!!)
     }
...
}



fun getistOfCategory(): {
  CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch() {
      ApiFunctions.getGenres(getApplication<Application>(), l -> listOfCategory.value = l)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain with an example?

Comment: Change your fun getGenres method signature so that it accepts a new param of type lambda which accepts List<Genre> as param and then implement a setter where you invoke this method

Comment: @AbdulRahmanShamair I've updated the answer so that it illustrates the idea a bit better

Comment: Ok, I have gotten pretty close, now on the initial launch of the application, the value of the list in the observer (in Fragment class) returns the size of the list to 0 but on rotation change, the updated value is retrieved by the observer, can we do something that in initial launch we could wait for the values from the server?

Comment: actually there should be no rotation required for that to work. can you please update your code above so i can have better insights

Comment: Ok, the error has gone, I just check the log files and the data is being updated after retrieval of new data from the server. Thanks a lot.